# Net 7 Oracle Managed Connection: ORA-04068 Package state exception repeats for all connections

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am using Oracle Managed connection in .Net 7 web api with connection pool enabled.

Whenever database team perform deployment, which might temporarily invalidate DB package state (which is resolved immediately by recompiling effected DB objects). At same time, if there is any open connection, it returns `ORA-04068: existing state of package has been discarded.` .

But even after DB packages are validated, still I am receiving same error.
Workaround to solve this issue is to reset Application pool in IIS.

Can this because of Pooling? I believe pool manager provide connection information, while above statement happens if command text executes. Then why this behavior, until I clear connections from pool (Reset IIS).

I also explicitly OracleConnection.ClearPool(connection) after each execution (test purpose), and I never face such issue.

I am searching best approach to manage connection pooling. As you can see my current approach is highly dependent.

following information for reference.

Runtime:   .Net 7
OD:        Oracle.ManageDataAccess.Core  3.21.1

```
try{
      OpenConnection();
      OracleCommand cmd = .......;
      await  cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
   }
 catch
  {
  }
 finally
 {
   connection.Close();
   connection.Dispose();
 // OracleConnection.ClearPool(connection);  // Clear pool explicitly. works
   connection = null;
 }
```

Comment: Based on your error message it seems that your application session's cached package state becomes invalid due to changes in dependent objects, often during deployments. Retained connections with outdated state usually cause the error. 
In order to fix the issue, you should try clearing the pool within a catch block specifically for ORA-04068, ensuring targeted handling. So uncomment the line, this is the way to get rid of the issue.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Can you please elaborate more; in which level cache happens. Let's separate DB connection and query execution (CommandText). I guess Pooling is responsible for connection management i.e. reuse existing connection regardless of command Text, So when Pool manager assign connection from pool, at that time there is no command text assigned. But it seems false. I want to know more about connection pooling

I am thinking the same approach to handle ORA error, and clear Pool just, so that new connection is created. But I am not sure, Is it best practices. 

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response, the pool manager maintains a cache of open connections that your application can reuse. When you close a connection, it is returned to the pool instead of being immediately closed and discarded. Let me know if that clear your confusion.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Agree; but is there any relation of underlaying query which is being executed. Because in my case, let's say if a store procedure is invalid, then it supposed to be erroneous to current open queries that using SP. Once SP is in valid state, then upcoming connections from Pool must work fine. 
This is not the case. I am getting SP invalid state error , until I reset application pool.

Comment: Yes, there's a relationship between the underlying query (stored procedure) and the behavior you're describing. where an error related to the invalid state of a stored procedure persists even after the stored procedure has been fixed—can be related to various factors, including how Oracle and ADO.NET handle cached metadata, connection pooling, and command execution.